# I've sandwiched $~\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}~$ with the inequalities.Can I proceed from here?

Tags: limits, inequality, limits-without-lhopital

I want to evaluate the following limit equation.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({1\over\sqrt{n^2+1^2}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2^2}}+\dots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}\right)
$$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({1\over\sqrt{n^2+1^2}}+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+2^2}}+\dots+{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}
\end{align}$$

**My tries**

I assume that $~n~$ takes a natural number.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{n^2+1}}
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{2n^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{n^2\left(1+{1\over n^2}\right)}}
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{2}n}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over n\sqrt{\left(1+{1\over n^2}\right)}}
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over\sqrt{2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over \sqrt{\left(1+{1\over n^2}\right)}}
$$

$$
\color{fuchsia}{0.707<{1\over\sqrt{2}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}\leq1
} 
$$

Can I proceed from here? Which means that this math problem is quoted from the college transfer exam in 1998 so I am worrying about that whether this pink inequalities got subtracted of score in an exam, as a final answer.

Comment: Using Riemann sums, $$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n^2  + i^2 } }}}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + (i/n)^2 } }}}  \to \int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\sqrt {1 + t^2 } }}}=\log(\sqrt{2}+1)=0.881373587\ldots
$$

Comment: I don't see how you can apply the Squeeze Theorem from the pink line. All you did was bound $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}$. The Squeeze Theorem requires the limit of the lower bound and the limit of the higher bound to go to some number.

Comment: @Accelerator I've changed the title of my this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum can be manipulated into a Riemann sum

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\equiv \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)\Delta x$$

which converges to the integral

$$\longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sinh^{-1}(1)$$

Comment: I think that the last term should be $~\log\left(\sqrt 2 + 1\right)~$ instead of $~\arcsin (1)~$. If the integrand was $~\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~$ then the primitive function is $~\arcsin x~$  I think.

Comment: @TG24 That's not arcsin.

Comment: @DavidP I completely missed out "h" X0.